# Load python module not from a file

Tags: python, unit-testing, module, import

I've got some python code in a library that attempts to load a simple value from a module that will exist for the applications that use this library

```
from somemodule import simplevalue
```

Normally, the application that uses the library will have the module file and everything works fine. However, in the unit tests for this library the module does not exist. I know that I can create a temporary file and add that file to my path at runtime, but I was curious if there is a way in python to load something in to memory that would allow the above import to work.

This is more of a curiosity, saying "add the module to your test path" is not helpful :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is. Use `types.ModuleType` to create a new module object, then add it to `sys.modules`:

```
sys.modules["somename"] = types.ModuleType("somename")
```

You can then do `import somename`. If you need to add classes or functions to it, import it before calling your test script, and just add functions to it:

```
def myfunc(x, y, z):
    ...

somename.myfunc = myfunc
```

It should go without saying, but just in case: this is largely an academic curiosity. It has some uses for testing, but other than that, stick to importing things the usual way.

Incidentally, how I know about this: I've come across the technique used in testing, to make a "stub" for the `_winreg` module on non-Windows systems. [Here it is](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/utils/tests/test_path.py) in use.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, worked perfectly. Yes I agree, this is not the pattern of code I want to be writing. But for this test scenario it works correctly.

Comment: @smullins: You're welcome. The warning was more for anonymous future readers than you, since you sound like you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't necessary to create a module. No Python code cares whether `somemodule.simplevalue` is actually a reference to an attribute of a module. To do so, a program would need to check the type of `somemodule`. Why bother?

Since you just want the single value from the module and are importing it into your own namespace, just define it:

```
simplevalue = 42
```

If you like, use `try/except` to try to import the real module first.

```
try:
    from somemodule import simplevalue
except ImportError:
    simplevalue = 42
```

If you are importing the entire module but only using one value, you can use a class to define a namespace.

```
try:
    import somemodule
except ImportError:
    class somemodule(object):
        simplevalue = 42
```

Now `somemodule.simplevalue` refers to the value regardless of whether the module is available.

If you want other modules that also import `somemodule` to see your faked-up class-as-module, as you would in your unit test, just do this afterward:

```
import sys
sys.modules["somemodule"] = somemodule
```

Comment: I'm amused that we both chose 42 as a value for `simplevalue` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your system under test (`sut` in my example) needs to be able to cope with the fact that `somemodule` may not exist, so you can trap the `ImportError`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    from somemodule import simplevalue
except ImportError, e:
    if 'somemodule' in e:
        '''We expect that to happen in the unittest but you should log something for when
         this happens in production'''

def fn():
    return simplevalue
```

Then you can inject a value in your unittest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import sut

class T(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fn(self):
        sut.simplevalue = 42
        self.assertEquals(42, sut.fn())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```